# CodeIgniter: is $_POST already clean for db input?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my first app with CI and I want to know whether $_POST is clean and can I directly insert the data into db?

I have enabled `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`

Thank You.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but [$this->input->post()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) called without parameters will return all items passed through an XSS filter.

Also, if you are using it, the [ActiveRecord](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) documentation for codeigniter states the following:

> It also allows for safer queries,
>   since the values are **escaped
>   automatically by the system**.

Comment: This answer is now wrong, if you want all items with XSS filter do $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE)

Answer (score 2):

If you use [CodeIgniter's Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) access to the database, you don't have to worry about escaping values as it takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, because SQL is made up of pretty standard alpha numeric characters ([the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)).  You should at the very least type your data and use php's `mysql_real_escape_string()` ([the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)).

This prevents SQL injection, whereas XSS filtering does not.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no
Long answer: maybe, if you use more secure DB methods

If you use a parametrized function (ex: pgSQL has pg_query_params()) then you don't need to sanitize the data, you only need to sanitize the data if you concat your SQL, which is generally considered subpar coding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like things have changed in the current version of CodeIgniter (2.0.0)...

`$this->input->post` does not work

and `$_POST` is automatically cleaned when `global_xss_filtering` is enabled.

Comment: $this->input->post has never worked. That is a property, not a method. You have always needed to provide a key name, but the next release will allow the first argument to be empty to return the whole array (cleaned).